# using Link in react does not re-render the component

Tags: reactjs

I am at route 'http://localhost:3000/detail/machine-learning-654a79f32638a8b300f9b92aae0f4a17' and after clicking some link on this page It will redirect me to page 'http://localhost:3000/detail/upsc-detail-654a79f32638a8b300f9b92aae0f4a17' using 'Link' from 'react-router-dom' but it does not re-render the component and shows the same content on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have your state updated on component update. Usually done using componentDidUpdate and render functions

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to reset some state variable in componentDidUpdate() method.